# How to configure ASP.NET MVC to use my OwinHost.exe started version of Identity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin

ASP.NET Identity is supposed to be `self hostable` as it's built on top of OWIN.

I have ASP.NET Identity running in location `http://localhost/5000` on my local machine, [with the help of this article](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection).

Up until now, I have been providing my ASP.NET MVC application with the following line to hook it up:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="owin:appStartup" value="OwinTest.Identity.OwinStart, OwinTest.Identity" />
</appSettings>
```

However, now that it is self hosted, I need to point my completely separate MVC application to use Identity Framework located at `http://localhost/5000`.

Hundreds of articles on the internet bang on about how ASP.NET Identity is built on OWIN and that it can be self hosted, but I can't find a single article out there that shows it being used as standalone middle-ware.  Most of the articles out there explain how to self host WebAPI, but this isn't much use for Identity Framework when it needs to hook into MVC (for the [Authorize] attribute to work, amongst other things).

**How do I configure my application to point to my self hosted version?**